# how to implement Char.IsCurrencySymbol?

Tags: c#, unicode

The c# standard library currently has a `Char.IsSymbol` Method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00k2wda1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could implement a `Char.IsCurrencySymbol` method?

```
Char.IsCurrencySymbol('$')
// true

Char.IsCurrencySymbol('@')
//false
```

Comment: Did you even tried *anything*? Can´t imagine why this gets upvoted.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think it is an awful question too, but OP self-answered a few minutes after posting. Not sure if it was intentional to not answer when posting, but it could have been a bad Q with a decent self-A.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Any answers given to a question should never affect the questions vote-score - even for self-answers. I agree OPs answer is good (although it´s the exact same as the accepted one which is probably why it was deleted). Anyway the question itself is bad.

Comment: Agreed, that is why I didn't upvote. @HimBromBeere

Comment: @HimBromBeere I guess it was indeed intended to be question with self answer, but so happened that I answered it faster than OP posted his self-answer... And I don't see why this question is considered so bad. Everyone knows today about unicode categories?

Comment: @Evk "Everyone knows today about unicode categories?" Of course not. But the question should stand for its own, regardsless of any answer. As it is the question doesn´t show any research. The answer on the other hand is of course perfectly valid and good, that´s why it was upvoted so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsCurrencySymbol(this char c)
    {
        return char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bool yes = '$'.IsCurrencySymbol();
bool no = '@'.IsCurrencySymbol();
```

Comment: I was about to write a RegEx version of this, but it's way clearer this way.